# Instagram API curl code command to php

Tags: php, shell, curl, php-curl

I can't find the curl equivalent in php for this command

```html
curl -F 'client_id=CLIENT_ID' \
    -F 'client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET' \
    -F 'grant_type=authorization_code' \
    -F 'redirect_uri=AUTHORIZATION_REDIRECT_URI' \
    -F 'code=CODE' \
    https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token
```

I know it should start like that

```html
$ch = curl_init('https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token');
curl_setopt($ch, something, ...); 
...
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the equivalents to

```
curl -F 'client_id=CLIENT_ID' \
    -F 'client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET' \
    -F 'grant_type=authorization_code' \
    -F 'redirect_uri=AUTHORIZATION_REDIRECT_URI' \
    -F 'code=CODE' \
    https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token
```

would be

```
$url = 'https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token';
$fields = array(
    'client_id' => 'CLIENT_ID',
    'client_secret' => 'CLIENT_SECRET',
    'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
    'redirect_uri' => 'AUTHORIZATION_REDIRECT_URI',
    'code' => 'CODE'
);

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```

Hope I helped! -CM

Comment: but what is $fields_string ? Do you mean $fields ?